# Ошибка синтаксиса при добавлении в таблицу

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Изучаю php mysql по книге, создал таблицу users и пытаюсь добавить данные, на что вылетает ошибка. Менял ковычки на одинарные и повторял дважды одинарные - не чего не вышло.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO users
-> VALUES (1, "Mike", "Greenfield", "mike@greenfieldguitars.com",
-> "http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=777666",
-> "@test1test");
ERROR 1064 (4200): Erreur de syntaxe pr\00E8s de '"Mike", "Greenfield", "mikegreenfieldguitars.com", "http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=777666", "@test1test", \00E0 la ligne 1
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Похоже, все дело в кодировке, но через phpmyadmin она не меняется и просит задать пароль root`у, который невозможно задать через консоль из за неправильной кодировки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А структура таблицы какая? Какие столбцы есть? автоинкремент у первого столбца или нет?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский столбцы добавил нужные для этих данных с правильными типами (извиняюсь, но я только начал учить бд и поэтому не знаю что такое автоинкремент и как его проверить) Все делаю по книге Бретта Маклафлина "Исчерпывающее руководство" и именно на этом моменте застрял

Comment: Ну добавьте например в вопрос то, что выводит  запрос `DESCRIBE users`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский добавил

Comment: Скорее всего, в имени Mike присутствует буква `è` (не `e`) - она нестандартная, а так просто сохранять в таблицу что-то, кроме латиницы, нельзя - надо настраивать collation и кодировки.

Comment: @yeputons ввел еще раз и использовал полностью латиницу - не получилось. Может будет важно, но установил готовую сборку WAMP с офф сайта

Comment: А, эм... почему сообщение об ошибке **на французском**? О_о

Comment: @D-side вот и я об этом тоже задумывался, когда она была) Видимо, сборка такая, но я не мог поставить язык при установки французский

Answer (score 1):

попробуй изменить кодировку на utf8_general_ci

напиши в консоли

```
ALTER TABLE users CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: через phpmyadmin попытался поменять кодировку - не получилось выдало такое сообщение "Конфигурационный файл phpMyAdmin содержит настройки MySQL по-умолчанию, согласно которым для привилегированного пользователя 'root' не задан пароль. Такие настройки делают MySQL-сервер уязвимым для несанкционированного доступа, поэтому настоятельно рекомендуется установить пароль для пользователя 'root'." Попытался задать пароль через консоль mysql - та же ошибка с синтаксисом

Comment: После команды не поменялось

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился удалением сборки WAMP и установки одного mysql. К сожалению, так и не понял почему такая магия произошла, но теперь данные успешно добавились. Спасибо всем, кто пытался помочь.

Answer (score 0):

А если написать по стандарту?

```
INSERT INTO users
VALUES (1, 'Mike', 'Greenfield', 'mike@greenfieldguitars.com',
'http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=777666',
'@test1test');
```

Answer (score -1):

Не знаю как из командной строки, но Вы забыли указать в какие поля записывать эти данные. Запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, name, surname, email, facebook, pass) VALUES (1, "Mike", "Greenfield", "mike@greenfieldguitars.com", "http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=777666", "@test1test");
```

Comment: Обычно, перечислять поля надо, если вставляются не во все из них. Если вставляются данные абсолютно во все поля - их имена не обязательно указывать

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать. Никогда не приходилось заполнять все поля)